# Unable to import dashboards in grafana

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm, grafana

I have grafana running in my Kubernetes cluster, installed as part of the `kube-prometheus-stack-13.10.0` helm chart, so I have Prometheus already configured as a data source.

But when I try to import any dashboard, I'm hit with a `not found` error?

[image]

What I expect to happen, is that the dashboard should get installed so I can visualize the metrics being exposed.

Am I possibly missing an additional configuration step?

Does anyone have any experience with adding dashboards to this helm chart?